# How to write content in child window using chrome packaged app?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, google-chrome-app

I have created the new child window using chrome.app.window.create API in order to print the content of window using window.print().but my question is how can i pass the content in that html.please could anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DOM of the new window is accessible via `window.document`.

The window here isn't the window passed to the `chrome.app.window.create` callback function (call it `createdWindow`), but rather `createdWindow.contentWindow`.

So, the DOM you're looking for is `createdWindow.contentWindow.document`. Modify that DOM however you like and then call `createdWindow.contentWindow.print()`.

UPDATE -- Here's the code following what I said above:

```
window.onload = function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('printwindow.html', {},
    function (createdWindow) {
      var win = createdWindow.contentWindow;
      win.onload = function () {
        win.document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML =
          '<p>Here is something to print.</p>';
        win.print();
      }
    }
  );
};
```

printwindow.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WindowToPrint</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tested this code and it works. I understand that the OP has gone another way, but it would be nice for others looking at this question if this could be marked as the answer.

Comment: how can i modify that DOM ? i was trying to write the content on that like chrome.app.window.create('Printwindow.html', function(_win) {
   _win.contentWindow.document.write('this is test content');
   _win.contentWindow.print();
  });

Comment: Try using `document.open()` first.

Comment: it says,document.write is not available in packaged app.

Comment: Xan,when i use document.open();its throw exception like document.open() is not available in packaged app.please find below my code: chrome.app.window.create('Printwindow.html', function(_win) {
   _win.contentWindow.document.open();
   _win.contentWindow.document.write('mansoor');
   _win.contentWindow.print();
  });

Comment: please help me..unable to write the content.as document.write() are disabled features in packaged app.

Comment: Don't use write(). Instead, modify the object structure (called the Document Object Model, or DOM) under the document object. What works for me is to start with a div in the HTML with an id of, say "content" and then set its HTML with something like: createdWindow.contentWindow.document.querySelect('#content').innerHTML = "<p>whatever html you want goes here</p>"; You can also create DOM objects directly and append them to the existing DOM. These DOM techniques aren't specific to Chrome Apps, so there is lots of documentation on them.

Comment: as per your suggestion i have created the div id in html as "content" in below find my code for your reference: chrome.app.window.create('Printwindow.html', function(_win) {
   _win.contentWindow.document.querySelect('#content').innerHTML = "<p>whatever html you want goes here</p>";
   _win.contentWindow.print();
  });but error is found like undefined is not a function.

Comment: Maybe the page hasn't been loaded? Put the code in a window.onload handler.

Comment: I have added code under onload handler like this:chrome.app.window.create('Printwindow.html', function(_win) {_win.contentWindow.addEventListener("load", function({_win.contentWindow.document.querySelect('#content').innerHTML = "<p>whatever html you want goes here</p>";_win.contentWindow.print();});});then too i am getting error as undefined is not a function.please help me.

Comment: thanking you a lot.. Marc and Xan,however finally i have done my printing requirement with help of indexeddb concepts.