# Access DOM of a web site via google packaged app

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

my aim is to write an app for chrome which communicates details of the DOM of a web page via  xhttprequest to a local web server.
In order to access the dom of a web site one would usually use tabs in combination with a content script like this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "www.example.com" });
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

And then use the messaging system to communicate the stuff to the background script.

Unfortunately when I do that, I need to add "tabs" permission to the manifest which is not allowed for packaged apps, only for extensions. I need to implement a packaged app because in a usual extension, no socket connection is allowed (which I need at some time).

I also tried what is suggested here: [How to write content in child window using chrome packaged app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487556/how-to-write-content-in-child-window-using-chrome-packaged-app)

However,

```
chrome.app.window.create
```

Does only work for local html files, not for external websites.

So my question again:
(how) is it possible in a packaged app to access the dom of a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a [<webview>](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) for Chrome apps and inject custom scripts via the [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-executeScript) method.

Remember to specify the `"webview"` permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I did it exactly as you said, Joseph Portelli.
The code:

**main.js**

```
 chrome.app.window.create('webview.html', {},
    function (createdWindow) {
      var win = createdWindow.contentWindow;
      win.onload = function () {
      var webview =  win.document.querySelector('#webview');
      webview.setAttribute("src", "http://www.example.com");
       webview.addEventListener("contentload", function () {

        webview.executeScript({file: "content_script.js"}, function(result) {});
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
          function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
              if(request.dom) {
                plugin.sendDom(request.dom, request.browser);
              }
          });
      });
    }
  });
```

**webview.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
        <webview id="webview" style="height:100%;width:100%"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**content_script.js**

```
...
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];    
var dom = {root: domTraverser.recurseDomChildren(body)};
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({dom:dom, browser: getBrowserName()});
```